# TFS configuration Access rejected

Tags: tfs

I'm configuring Team Server Foundation in my server. But just the installation ends, I try access with the default user: `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`.
The problem basically is when I can't access to this user to my domain (The domain is up), but when the page request me the password, the password is always wrong (I tried with the local users and I don't have any other user). 
And I can't change the password and authentication, the error message is:

```
TF257014 The authentication mode is currently set to NTLM. You cannot change the authentication mode to negotiate (Kerberos). This change is not allowed because the computer is not a member of an Active Directory domain.
```

Comment: It's strongly recommended to run TFS under the identity of a dedicated service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be confused by the account *running* TFS. Seems that you are in "workgroup" mode, so use (create) local accounts on the TFS machine and use those to access. Keep in mind that the account you used to install TFS has administrative privileges on TFS.